# Can AngularJS architecture interfere with a framework like Ruby on Rails at some point?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a web application that has most of it's logic on ruby on rails, and lately I've been getting good at AngularJS but I'm not a master at it.  What I like about angular is that it lets you be very declarative on your javascript code knowing if an element is being referenced on the html unlike jquery. Also it has nice filtering options but that would not be needed cause rails handles that on the server-side. Is AngularJS meant to work as a stand alone framework or it can coexist with server-side frameworks?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a discussion question, so not an [ideal SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Angular and Rails can happily coexist. 
You can use the asset pipeline and load Angular, in the same way that you would any other JS library.

There is a [good tutorial here](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails),  also, [this Railscast is quite handy](http://railscasts.com/episodes/405-angularjs) although it is a bit out of date now.

My advice is to have a crack at it, and then come back to SO and post specific bugs or challenges you are hitting.

Comment: thanks my friend, I'm still learning the stackoverflow "rules" for posting....It's not clear enough what's a "good" question and what's not....I only got downvotes on software arquitecture type of questions and similar, which I'm starting to believe I should post somewhere else and come here with specific questions about coding

Comment: Yes, I sometimes get voted down and it's not always clear why. I think they don't like posts that promote length discussion. They prefer specific code related questions that can have a clear best answer.